# Convert Column Values into Row Names using R

Tags: r, reshape

I need to Convert Column Values into Row Names using R.

For example to convert format1 into format2

```
var<-c("Id", "Name", "Score", "Id", "Score", "Id", "Name")
num<-c(1, "Tom", 4, 2, 7, 3, "Jim")
format1<-data.frame(var, num)

format1

    var num
1    Id   1
2  Name Tom
3 Score   4
4    Id   2
5 Score   7
6    Id   3
7  Name Jim
```

Be careful, there are missing values in the format1,and that's the challenge, I guess.

```
Id<-c(1, 2, 3)
Name<-c("Tom", NA, "Jim")
Score<-c(4, 7, NA)
format2<-data.frame(Id, Name, Score)

format2

  Id Name Score
1  1  Tom     4
2  2 <NA>     7
3  3  Jim    NA

# How to convert format1 into format2?
```

I may not articulate in the exact way, however, you can refer to the toy data i give above.

I know a litter bit about reshape and reshape2, however, I failed in converting the data format using both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
format1$ID <- cumsum(format1$var == "Id")
format2 <- reshape(format1, idvar = "ID",timevar = "var", direction = "wide")[-1]
names(format2) <- gsub("num.", "", names(format2)
#   Id Name Score
# 1  1  Tom     4
# 4  2 <NA>     7
# 6  3  Jim  <NA>
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to skip the `gsub()` step, you could directly specify the output column names via the `varying` argument:

```
reshape(format1, idvar = "ID",timevar = "var", direction = "wide",
        varying = list(c("Id", "Name", "Score")))[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dcast` after adding an identifier column.

```
format1$pk <- cumsum( format1$var=="Id" )
library(reshape2)
dcast( format1, pk ~ var, value.var="num" )
```

Comment: very good idea of constructing pk. However, the result of dcast is not exactly the same with format2 i give above. Do you mind check the result again?

Comment: ;df <- as.data.frame(t(reshape(format1,idvar=c('var'),timevar='pk',direction='wide') ));
colnames(df) <- df[1, ]; 
df<- df[-1, ]